# Can I show the different methods of death penalties as well as predict future years

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to be able to predict the rise/fall in death penalties for this dataset below
This is USA 1976 death penalty data found at: https://www.kaggle.com/usdpic/execution-database.
I want to have the Y axis showing amount of death penaitlies over the years and using different colours show the different methods, with the x axis showing the count of deaths penalities from 1999 onwards
This is my code so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

res = df[~(df['Date'] < '1999-01-01')]

print(res)
Count = res['Date'].value_counts()
print(Count)
time= df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date']=df['Date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
print (time)
x = np.array(time)
y = np.array(Count)
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=1/3, random_state=0)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
 ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1442, 834]
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please add a bit more detail about which specific part you are stuck on (also what you've tried and the error message that's come up)?

Comment: Yeh sorry, I am stuck as it comes up with an error, This is the error '
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1442, 834]'

Comment: Does the error come up when you run the last line of code (the train_test_split)?

Comment: yeh it does, I think its due to my editing of code previoulsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to reshape your data so that you have a time series for each "method", which you can then use in a predictive model. It's probably worth pointing out that the distribution of "Method" is really skewed (values are from 1999 onwards), so it will be very difficult/impossible to forecast most of them:

```
df['Method'].value_counts()

# Lethal Injection    923
# Electrocution        17
# Gas Chamber           1
# Firing Squad          1
```

Here is a solution that will help you reshape your data to get time series data for each "Method" (I've added a bit more of an explanation at the end):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df[df['Date'].dt.year >= 1999]

df = df.set_index('Date')

df2 = df.groupby('Method').resample('1M').agg('count')['Name'].to_frame()

df2 = df2.reset_index().pivot(index='Date',columns='Method',values='Name').fillna(0)

df2.plot()
```

[image]

We can check that the new shape of the data gives us the correct number of "Method" counts:

```
df2.sum()

# Method
# Electrocution        17.0
# Firing Squad          1.0
# Gas Chamber           1.0
# Lethal Injection    923.0
```

Explained

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Filter out rows where date values where the year is less than 1999
df = df[df['Date'].dt.year >= 1999]

# Set the index to be the datetime
df = df.set_index('Date')

# This bit gets interesting - we're grouping by each method and then resampling
# within each group so that we get a row per month, where each month now has a
# count of all the previous rows associated with that month. As the dataframe is
# now filled with the same count value for each column, we arbitrarily take the 
# first one which is 'Name'
# Note: you can change the resampling frequency to any time period you want, 
# I've just chosen month as it is granular enough to cover the whole period
 
df2 = df.groupby('Method').resample('1M').agg('count')['Name'].to_frame()

#                              Name
# Method           Date            
# Electrocution    1999-06-30     1
#                  1999-07-31     1
#                  1999-08-31     1
#                  1999-09-30     0
#                  1999-10-31     0
# ...                           ...
# Lethal Injection 2016-08-31     0
#                  2016-09-30     0
#                  2016-10-31     2
#                  2016-11-30     1
#                  2016-12-31     2

df2 = df2.reset_index().pivot(index='Date',columns='Method',values='Name').fillna(0)

# Method      Electrocution  Firing Squad  Gas Chamber  Lethal Injection
# Date                                                                  
# 1999-01-31            0.0           0.0          0.0              10.0
# 1999-02-28            0.0           0.0          0.0              12.0
# 1999-03-31            0.0           0.0          1.0               7.0
# 1999-04-30            0.0           0.0          0.0              10.0
# 1999-05-31            0.0           0.0          0.0               6.0
# ...                   ...           ...          ...               ...
# 2016-08-31            0.0           0.0          0.0               0.0
# 2016-09-30            0.0           0.0          0.0               0.0
# 2016-10-31            0.0           0.0          0.0               2.0
# 2016-11-30            0.0           0.0          0.0               1.0
# 2016-12-31            0.0           0.0          0.0               2.0
```